# Unknown issuer - error suddenly appeared without modifying my own code or updating dependencies

Tags: php, jwt, dependencies, jose

I got this error from a JWT dependency package when trying to connect to an API :

> "Uncaught Jose\Component\Checker\InvalidClaimException: Unknown issuer"

in "\vendor\web-token\jwt-checker\IssuerChecker.php"

Application was working fine for a year but this error appeared from one day to another without I modify my own code nor update my dependencies.

The API is working fine for other people.

Note that I connect to the API from a WAMP on my personal computer (localhost / no domain / no SSL)

I tried to understand the issue but found little on the Internet.

Can it comes from my Self Signed SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes it is a possibility if your API server is using a self-signed SSL certificate